# Wordpress how to assign some post for any post

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress  I have one post id with 299 i can see the post in page wile display this page right side or left side. I would like to see some of the post (Like related post or recent post), but that list based on what ids I assigned under 299 that list only need to display.

That post are child for the parent post id 299.

Example: I added one Destination as one post 299 as id. I would like to get the hotels related to this post. I added the hotels also like post. 100,239, 345 these 3 post (hotels) only need to comes under this post. Is this possible?

Please suggest if any plugin available related to this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using pages

There are plugins available that can show all sub-pages of the current page as links in a widget.

Have a look at [BE Subpages Widget](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/be-subpages-widget/), it should do what you want.

> This widget will dynamically list a section's subpages. When on a page, it will find the section's top level page and list its children.
>
> It can also include the current page's subpages in listing.

#### Using posts

If you are using posts and thus cannot build a hierarchy, you will need to use tags or categories to create the connection between your destination and hotels.

Have a look at [Related Posts By Taxonomy](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/related-posts-by-taxonomy/), which can show posts with the same tags or category as the current post.

Comment: I have the post ex: http://way2tour.com/pykara-lake-and-pykara-falls-in-ooty/ from this link( this is a POST not Page) so this case i need to assign some of the POST under this post. when i come to this i can see the right side what i assigned as child for this post

Comment: I missed that in your question. Updated my answer to also include a suggestion for posts.